# TSQL 2 optional parameters

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005, optional-parameters

I have a simple query like so:

```
SELECT * FROM orders
```

that returns all orders, simple.

I would like to add optional parameters to my query.

```
DECLARE @group INT;
SET @group = 1 --IT1

SELECT * FROM orders WHERE group = isnull(@group, group)
```

This also works fine.

My problem is that i need a second parameter like so:

```
DECLARE @group INT;
SET @group = 1 --IT1
DECLARE @department VARCHAR(8);
SET @department = 'IT'

SELECT * FROM orders WHERE /*and here add limitation with department*/ group = isnull(@group, group)
```

My orders table has column GROUP, but no column DEPARTMENT.

Situation looks like so:
I have 2 comboboxes. One for departments, second for group.
In first I have options:

- All
- IT
- CALL CENTRE

Second is populated when user select something from combo1.
If he selects IT the group combo box will have options:

- All
- IT1
- IT2

If user select from first combo department and then group it is easy because I then check only group.
Problem is when he wants all orders from department IT.

Here is how groups are assigned to departments

- IT - 1,2,5
- CALL CENTRE - 4,6
- PRINT - 3

Any ideas?

ADDED:

I have created something like that:

```
DECLARE @group INT;
SET @group = 1 --IT1
DECLARE @department VARCHAR(8);
SET @department = 'IT'

SELECT * FROM orders WHERE
(@department IS NULL OR (@department='IT' AND group IN (1,2,5)) OR (@department='PRINT' AND group =3))
     AND
     (@group IS NULL OR group = @group)
```

I don't know if it is corrent, it somehow works :)

Comment: The SQL query is defined and executed where? (is this a .net program?)

Comment: It is a report in aspx, I need to choose all orders from my criteria and then process them and display results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might pretend you have a table by using CTE populated with records via union all. Then perform a join and a check. If you prefer CTE might be replaced with derived table.

```
; WITH departments (DepartmentID, GroupID) as (
  select 'IT', 1
  union all
  select 'IT', 2
  union all
  select 'IT', 5
  union all
  select 'CALL CENTRE', 4
  union all
  select 'CALL CENTRE', 6
  union all
  select 'PRINT', 3
)
SELECT * 
FROM orders 
  INNER JOIN departments
     ON orders.[group] = departments.GroupID
WHERE (@Group is null OR [group] = @group)
  AND (@department is null OR DepartmentID = @department)
```

Comment: You save my day second time :) I'll check it right away. Your solution looks so smooth and easy to implement :) I'll check it right away.

Comment: This one works just fine :) But again should I use solution from my question or this one? I have about 500k records in my orders table.

Comment: @Misiu I cannot tell without testing. Could you time both solutions with different parameters?

Comment: Yes :) that's not a problem to test them. I just need to select big amount of data from my table. Because when I select 1k of records they have almost same times. I'll check them without select top 1000. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Here is the query. In the front end, when a single group is selected, you assign the @group variable, just like you did before. When no single group is selected, you assign the flag for department. So if all IT was selected you set @allIT to 1 (or whatever, as long as it is not NULL) and proceed like so:

```
SELECT * FROM orders 
WHERE (@group = NULL OR group = @group)
AND
(@allIT = NULL OR group = 1 or group = 2 or group = 3)
AND
(@allCallCenter = NULL OR group = 4 or group = 5)
...
```

If nothing is selected in a combobox, set that parameter value to NULL.

Comment: But I have no column department in my table. I know that department IT has groups 1,2,5. But there aren't any informations in database :/ I can't change that

Comment: Can you grab department from the combobox from the front-end? So if IT is selected, you provide @department='IT' and @group=NULL